# Can a universal charger power my monitor

Tags: display

I have a LG monitor that has a 19V 2A power supply can a universal charger power my monitor if it has 19V in it?

Comment: If it's capable of providing 19V and 2A then yes, probably.

Comment: Also make sure the charger polarity (+ -) matches the Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can find the universal charger output on it, such as 19V 2A. You said it is 19V, so the current ≥2A means that this universal charger can power up your monitor.
And then, please make sure the universal charger's connector is suitable for your LG monotor.